# I would like to create new postgres sql DB for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku

I have deployed an application in Heroku. It is Rails applications. The DB is postgres. So this is the app in heroku. Now I want to create new app which will be a clone of the previous app. But it will have separate DB. How should I get going? I would also like to know about configuring the DB from heroku. I am not so techy so please go easy on me.

Thanks!

Comment: Just create a new app and clone it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But it will have separate DB

So, just create a new heroku app, add PG add-on to it, and that's it. No more steps. It will have a separate database. I think you don't even have to add PG add-on, it probably is added by default.

If you wanted two apps use the same DB, *then* you'd have to do extra steps.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have created 2 apps and added the add on. Now the thing, first app that I had is live DB. The other 2 should work as test. How should I go doing it?

Comment: @RaxitAlphaLogic: what specifically is the problem there?

Comment: I have created 2 apps and added PG add on. Lets say main app is ABC and its DB is ABCDB, first clone app is DEF and its DB is DEFDB and second clone app is GHI and its DB is GHIDB. Now when the team performs over the GHIDB, the main app ABC is affected. How should I go doing it?

Comment: @RaxitAlphaLogic: make sure that DATABASE_URL variable on those 3 apps has different values and not the same one on all 3 apps

Comment: Great! It worked. Thank you. Since my reputation is quite low, I am unable to vote. But it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Heroku Fork](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app#fork-application) to clone your application. This will copy the app, environment variables and any postgres databases (and their data if you want it) to a separate Heroku application.

```
heroku fork --from old-app-name --to new-app-name
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I get an error saying could not fork. What went wrong?

Comment: I have no idea. Did the error have any other useful information?

Comment: The error is: `Connection rejected: could not fork new process for connection: Unknown error`